# AngularJS do not sort in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS do not sort in ng-repeat.
I did,

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
  <div id="tasks" >
    <h3>{{ list.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:'card.position'" ng-if="list._id == card.list">{{ card.position }}<button ng-click="take(card.position)">HERE</button>{{ $index }}</li>
      </ul>
      <form ng-submit="addTask(list._id, $index, newTask)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="add a new task" required />
        </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>


console.log($scope.cards[0]);
```

And output of the above code is :

```
Object { _id: "59bc0936c84be51d70f786e7", name: "first", list: "59bbdeae1ebcd215a4b7af62", position: 7200, __v: 0, created: "2017-09-15T17:09:10.813Z", updated: "2017-09-15T17:09:10.813Z" }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF3k4.jpg

Where could I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be just **`orderBy:'position'`**

```
<li ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:'position'" ng-if="list._id == card.list">{{ card.position }}<button ng-click="take(card.position)">HERE</button>{{ $index }}</li>
```

**`EDIT`**

if you want to ordery by multiple fields, put them inside an array like this,

```
<li ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:['position','list']" ng-if="list._id == card.list">{{ card.position }}<button ng-click="take(card.position)">HERE</button>{{ $index }}</li>
```